# MongoDB Java Driver - How to disable Cursor Timeout in aggregation query?

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to run an aggregation on a big collection using Mongo Java Driver 3.0.4. On small samples of my collection everything works great, but when I tried to execute it on the whole collection I ended up with `MongoCursorNotFoundException`. I found out it is a problem of the Cursor that times out and gets closed by the server.

However, I cannot understand how to set this option. The aggregate() function returns an [AggregateIterable](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/client/AggregateIterable.html), which only has `useCursor` method that seems kinda relevalt. On the other hand, the find() function returns [FindIterable](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/async/client/FindIterable.html#noCursorTimeout-boolean-), which has a handy `noCursorTimeout(Boolean)` method. I cannot see why it is so simple on find, but there's no obvious way for this option on aggregate. How should I make sure the Cursor won't fail after a while?

My code so far is this.

```
AggregateIterable<Document> iterable = db.getCollection("tweets").aggregate(asList( new Document("$sort", new Document("timestamp_ms", 1)),
        new Document("$group", new Document("_id", "$relatedTrend")
                            .append("count", new Document("$sum", 1))
                            .append("tweets", new Document("$push", new Document("timestamp_millis", "$timestamp_ms")))))).allowDiskUse(true);

iterable.forEach(new Block<Document>() {
    @Override
    public void apply(final Document document) {
    //parse field "tweets" of document and do a lot of calculations.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this MongoDB JIRA [ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8188). You can increase the idle cursor time out when starting an instance of `mongod` or `mongos`:

```
mongod --setParameter cursorTimeoutMillis=<num>
```

or

```
mongos --setParameter cursorTimeoutMillis=<num>
```

If this is not an option, you can also run the following shell command:

```
use admin
db.runCommand({setParameter:1, cursorTimeoutMillis: <num>})
```